# Fragment getting overlapped in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, baseadapter

I am getting overlapped Fragments in PageViewer of Android .

PFB my layout for PageViewer

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="900dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs" >

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </TabWidget>
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I am calling it via my First Fragment Say FragmentA of first Tab . I need to replace it with Fragment A1 
 Calling this from the button click of list from BaseAdapter

```
Fragment duedateFrag = new FieldVisitFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, duedateFrag);

            ft.commit();
```

My Fragment gets called but its overlapped on viewpager .
The tabs runs from below the new Fragment . kindly help

On the hindsight , I think somewhere Nested Fragment or Child Fragment should come into play . Please guide.

Comment: what are you doing with "FrameLayout" and  "android.support.v4.view.ViewPager" both are different in your case correct

Comment: I am having 4 tabs and with viewPager I am scrolling those tabs

Comment: on each tabs I have separate Fragment shown for each tab

Comment: Then what is the "FrameLayout", are you try to add the fragment correct

Comment: I did not understand the what you want to achieve using ViewPager

Comment: Yes ... this is my first project in ViewPager . So I am trying to replace the fragment on Tab1 having Fragment A with another FragmentA1 on button click

Comment: Yes under stand that point but you are try to put the tab in ViewPager

Comment: Using ViewPager I can scroll through Tabs as Pages

Comment: can you edit the question with share your code

Comment: Yes ... its working fine as per tabs .. I can scroll through tabs

Comment: Ok then I see that you try to add " ft.add(android.R.id.tabcontent, duedateFrag);" the fragment instead of replace try using replace method

Comment: The problem comes when I want say Tab A having Fragment A to be entirely replaced by Fragement A1 . because its getting overlapped

Comment: Replace will sure help you actually add will add fragment over an over another fragment

Comment: Using replace aslo the same issue I checked

Comment: Just simple replace the content of your frame layout it is call R.id.tabcontent

Comment: Can you tell me all this you are doing inside the fragment or activity. I mean your parent is activity or fragment

Comment: It gives error when I do that

Comment: I am doing this as in Activity as seen below SampleActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77775/discussion-between-project-android-and-bhavdip-pathar).

Comment: Is this what you need @ProjectAndroid - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18719544/1479511

Comment: Nope @DroidWormNarendra

Answer (score 1):

I have used **ViewPager**, extending from **PagerAdapter**. I think you're not referencing the correct layout, you're using id/**tabcontent**. I can show an example of what I did, and I think you can follow the same.

In the Fragment xml:

```
<LinearLayout
...
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
...
</LinearLayout>
```

In Fragment code :

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
```

In the ViewPager code,

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
...
View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);
...
return view
}
```

Note: I did not use FragmentTransaction class for displaying the fragment or the tab view.

Keep us posted...

Comment: @Original Android : I have posted alternate question with total developmnents https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233001/fragment-does-not-get-displayed-in-viewpager

Comment: @ProjectAndroid, This is almost like answering twice for the same "alternate" question. Perhaps better would be just to edit your original question, though a lot changed. This way many comments are kept. Do you think my current posted answer is helpful at all?